# string isn't printing the complete line in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in `C++` and i'm trying to print this program:

```
    Enter string:
    This is a test

Output:
    This

Press any key to continue . . .
```

here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[100];
    cout << "Enter string: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << name << endl;
}
```

I'm completely confused why it's printing `this` here?

I'm from `Java` background as far as i know it must suppose to print completely `string` but nothing happens such?

Please explain me!

Comment: `cin >> name;` --> `cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY make that an answer so I can uptick it please.

Comment: Wow.. this one working too.. thanks :)

Comment: @WhozCraig: "The missing ingredient is you need a std::string; not a char[] buffer," .. If i use `string` i get this one error ..see this [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/5w997eqpj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));` instead of `cin >> name;`.